# "DISTINCT" is eliminated "ORDER BY" in subquery and "ORDER BY" is also slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to do `order by` in subquery and then `distinct on` on main query instead but why the ordering was eliminated or reset. Actually it should be descending as i wanted if i do only one `select` statement with `distinct on` and `order by` on the same level. I would like to understand why i do `distinct on` likes query below it will be eliminated the ordering.

query :

```
select distinct on (id) * from (

select * from products

left outer join product_descriptions on product_descriptions.product_id = products.id

order by id desc) as A
```

Result :

```
id  product_name                            price       
1   Navy Floral Embroidery Bomber Jacket    1390
2   Black Floral Embroidery Bomber Jacket   1390
3   Blue Wandy Blouse                       750
4   White Adele Pants                       1790
5   White Wandy Blouse                      750
6   Black Wandy Blouse                      750
7   Navy Adele Pants                        1790
```

I have a question because i am attempting to move `distinct on` to difference level of `order by` because it is faster as i tried but the ordering will be eliminated. I am solving a very slow query problem from this query.

```
with recursive categ_all as
(
    select *, id as root_category,array_append(null,id) as category_path
    from categories
    where parent_id is null

    union all
    select c.*, p.root_category,array_append(p.category_path,c.id)
    from categories c
    join categ_all p on c.parent_id[1] = p.id
)

select * from products as p 

left outer join categ_all on categ_all.id = ANY (p.category_ids)

order by p.created_at limit 20
```

I see that when i removed `order by` or removed `left outer join` with array. it will be faster but i still need to use an array.
Thanks for advice.

Comment: Try ordering in the outer query instead of the inner.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images, or links to images.)

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow/com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: @jarlh  Please, I have added more info.

Comment: Thanks all, I found the solution by using "unnest" instead of "any" operation. It is better.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a subquery for this:

```
select distinct on (p.id) *
from products p join
     product_descriptions pd
     on p.id = pd.product_id
order by p.id;
```

In general, you should not depend on ordering in subqueries to accomplish what you want.  You should have the explicit ordering at the same level as the `distinct on`.

I would also advise you to use qualified column names for all column references.  You might also want a second key for the `order by`, to specify *which* product description you want.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have added more info. Please help.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution by using "unnest" instead of "any" operation. It is better.